# Can you create a new window from a non-main window?

Tags: interface

If I have a window that is opened via `Window -> New Window` and I want to copy that window layout to a new 3rd window, is there any way to do that? There is no window menu on the window I want to copy because it is not a main window.

Can I convert a non-main Window to a main window (add the menu)? Or can I spawn a new main (or non-main) window based on an already opened and configured non-main window?

The goal is to create a new window with only one view like I already have in my second window, without the chore of cloning the main window and doing the "join area" Tetris puzzle.

This is a recent 2.8 Beta.

Comment: If I choose "window -> new main window" it creates a new window that is a copy of the main window. I want to create a 3rd window that is a copy of the 2nd window, but the 2nd window has no menu to choose "new window" from.

Comment: Change the editor type of your second window to "Info" instead of 3D View or whatever you currently have open. That will bring back the window drop down. Alternatively your could just shift click and drag the top right corner of the second window.

Comment: I use Window > Duplicate Window function and it allows me to create several copies of the main window. I can edit layout in the second and it will be copied to third, all windows will remain "linked" though, so e.g. rendering process will be synced etc. but as the window is fully copied menu with Window > Duplicate Window [remains accessible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpWoH.gif). Did you mean something else?

Comment: @LukasValine: This is the answer: "your could just shift click and drag the top right corner of the second window".